# Авторизация на сайте,проверка с помощью Ajax(Jquery)

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-form

Не могу понять ,почему Success не работает.(Я только учусь)
Нормально авторизацию проходит ,если написать правильные данные, но Алерт не показывает.
и если элс пишу тоже не работает.

JQUERY

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#logbutton').click(function(){
            var username = $('#user').val();
            var password = $('#pass').val();
            var login = 'login';


            if(username != '' && password != ''){
                $.ajax({
                    url:"index.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{username:username, password:password, login:login},
                    success:function(res){
                        if(res == "ok"){
                             alert('successfully logged in')
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            else{
                alert('All Fields are required!');
            }

        })


    })
```

PHP Code

```
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM players WHERE username = '".$user."' AND password = '".$pass."'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($sql) == 1){

        $array = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
        $_SESSION['user'] = $array['id'];
        echo "ok";



    }else{

        $loginerror = "<div class='alert alert-warning'>Invalid Login information.Please return to the <a href='/Artur/'>previous page</a></div>";
    }

}
```

Comment: смотрите в консоли браузера ошибки

Comment: @Pyramidhead ,простите,не понял,что?

Comment: @G.Denis,ошибок нету в консоли

Comment: @TsKinGT, добавьте обработчик `error`, `complete`, `done` и смотрите что из этого будет вызываться.

Comment: @Pyramidhead Ничего не вызывается .

Comment: А вы добавили обработку `error`, `complete`, `done`?

Comment: @Pyramidhead
   error: function(error){
       alert(error)
      },
      complete:function(){
       alert('login successfully completed')
      }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, в приведенном коде, он как минимум не знает что делать, если логин зафейлится. Ни со стороны клиента, ни со стороны сервера.

Сельский вариант:
Либо:

```
if(res == "ok"){
    alert('successfully logged in');
}else{
    alert('some fail here');
}
```

Либо

```
//php
...
}else{
    $loginerror = "Invalid Login information.Please return to the previous pagе";
    echo $loginerror; //Ну не просто так же присваивать переменной такой длинный текст? Все же выведем его
}


//js
...
if(res == "ok"){
    alert('successfully logged in');
}else{
    alert(res); // Дабы мы не зря выводили текст с сервера, передадим его пользователю
}
```

Более осмысленный вариант:

```
//php
...
if( `успешные условия логина` ){
    $response[status] = 1;
}else{
    $response[error] = 'Some error';//в зависимости от того, что стало причиной ошибки - формируем текст ошибки
}
echo json_encode($response);

//js
...
success:function(data){
    var response = JSON.parse(data);
    if(response.status){
         alert('You have been successfully logged in.');
    }else{
         alert(response.error);
    }
```

Comment: все равно не работает. всегда срабатывает else.

Comment: Какой именно вариант, и какой именно `else`

Comment: 2 вариант, в successe else работает всегда.. то есть всегда и при вводе правильного и при вводе неправильного логина и пароля выводится алерт со всем HTML тегами + в самом верху ОК или НО

Comment: Что за HO? Ну если он алертит вместе с ОК, то посмотри, почему у тебя сервер выкидывает и ОК и Ошибку одновременно.

Comment: смотри я сделал так. 
success:function(data){
       if(data == "ok"){
 window.location.replace('home.php')
 }
 else{
      alert(data);
 }
}

а в PHP когда инфа неправильная делается echo "no".

вот у меня если правильно ввести инфу выскакивает алерт с содержанием типо :  ОК и  внизу все теги мои .
а если ввести неправильную информацию то выскакивает такой же алерт только сверху написано NO

Comment: проблема в том ,что вот в моя переменная data из function(data) не получает содержание yes или no .. она получает yes или no + все теги

Comment: Ну дак и ищи почему. Я ж не телепат, код на расстоянии не вижу. Где то на серверсайд файле косяк с условием, посмотри, все ли там верно

Comment: ,спасибо большое , все получилось)) весь день мучился .

Answer (score 0):

```
success:function(res){
if(res == "ok"){
    alert('successfully logged in')
}
```

Твой php скрипт по ходу не возвращает OK. 
Прости что не по теме, но, может, стоило бы начать с более простых примеров изучение ajax?
[How to Use jQuery’s $.ajax() Function](https://www.sitepoint.com/use-jquerys-ajax-function/)